# Vue mqtt throws an error as ws does not work in the browser

Tags: vue.js, mqtt, ws

I am really new to vue and for this project I am trying to connect my code with MQTT HOST URL `ws://21.17.0.1:9009/`. When I use the same code and run on local laptop as from XAMP LOCALHOST, it works fine without any error. When I push the code to my company server and try to run the same code then it throws me an error as `ws does not work in the browser. Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object`. Is it because I am defining ws url inside mqtt.connect?

**SCRIPT**

```
runMqtt() {
  var mqtt = require('mqtt');
  var client  = mqtt.connect('ws://21.17.0.1:9009/');
}

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('route_status', function (err) {
     if (!err) {
       client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
      }
    })
  })

 var message = {command: "tap", route_status: "TRUE"};
 var obj = JSON.stringify(message);
 client.publish('server_commands', obj, {qos: 1});
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63601278/edit) the question to show the whole actual error message from the browser console. Also what browser are you testing with?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the mqtt.js code supports WebSockets in a brower (as your error message states.)  You might want to try Steve's tutorial:  http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/using-javascript-mqtt-client-websockets/ ...which uses a different library to do ws from a browser.  Or... just try a different method like 'mqtt://' or 'tcp://'

Comment: MQTT.JS does support websockets (`ws://`) and this is the ONLY transport that will work in the browser. Using `mqtt://` or `tcp://` will fail.